# Evaluating $ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\prod_{k=0}^{n}\left (1+a^{2^k}\right )$, where $|a|<1$

Tags: limits

Was practicing some undergraduate admission tests when I got this. It's a "select the answer" kind of test so I've managed to get the limit result correctly, but I do not know how to solve it.
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \hspace{3mm} {\prod_{k=0}^{n}}\left (1+a^{2^{k}}\right ),\left | a \right | < 1
$$

If would like some tips on how to approach this.

Thanks

Comment: If you multiply and divide by $1-a$ the product in the numerator $(1-a)(1+a)(1+a^2)(1+a^4)(1+a^{8})...(1+a^{2^n})$ will collapse to $1-a^{2^{k+1}}$. So, you get $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1-a^{2^{k+1}}}{1-a}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $1+a^{2^k} = \dfrac{1-a^{2^{k+1}}}{1-a^{2^k}}$